# Store permanent value in a variable on first time execution of the code, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

```
function filterListBox() {
  debugger;
  var txtValue = document.getElementById('<%=txtSearchUser.ClientID %>').value; //to get entered value to search
  var lstbox = document.getElementById('<%=lstMembers.ClientID %>');
  var opt;
  var array = new Array();
  var array1 = new Array();
  array = lstbox.options; //array value is 8

  if (txtValue != '') {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(txtValue) > -1) {
        opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.text = array[i].text;
        opt.value = array[i].value;
        array1.push(opt); // only pushes names that match the search filter

      }

    }
    lstbox.options.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.text = array1[i].text;
      opt.value = array1[i].value;
      lstbox.add(opt); // displays the pushed names that matched the search filter
    }

  }
  else {
    lstbox.options.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.text = array[i].text;
      opt.value = array[i].value;
      lstbox.add(opt);
    }
  }

}
```

In the above code, when I first run the code, the value of variable `array` is 8.  But as it enters the `if(txtValue != '')` it starts filtering through the names and pushes only those names in the `array1` that match the entered value (`txtValue`). Then it displays only those names.

The issue here is, when I am entering another value for `txtValue` it is searching for that value in the updated array options and not the original array. So the returned result is not correct. I am humbly asking for a solution to reset the array to its original options and search through the whole array and not the updated array.

Thank you. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Copy options to permanent array first, then use it.

```
var lstbox, allOptions;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    lstbox = document.getElementById('<%=lstMembers.ClientID %>');
    allOptions = Array.from(lstbox.options);
});
```

Change

```
array = lstbox.options;
```

to this

```
array = allOptions;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just tried but the value of `allOptions` is empty for me.  I am new to this method so I can't understand why.  Can you think of why or kindly suggest some other way? Thanks.

Comment: Then you are filling the listbox after dom loaded. You can set allOptions after filling the list. I can't see your full code.